# Using one main game loop to run all functions in a game (As3)

Tags: actionscript-3

Basically, i need to make a platform game, side scrolling beat em up.

Here’s some psuedo code.

Main timeline, add enter frame listenr, gameLoop

```
function gameLoop   

//start screen
If(current frame is 2(start screen)
{then run this code}    

If(current frame is 3(options)
{run this code] 

if(current frame is 4(level1)
{add key listeners, gravity();, movement();, collision();, score(); etc}    

if(current frame is 5, (death screen)
{do this code}
```

Will this be efficient coding or there a better way?

Vesper, did you mean something like this?

```
    public function Main() 
    {
        //iniation players
        character = new player;
        timmy = new SirTimmy;
        caroline = new princess;
        //stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainGameLoop)

        //check EnterFrames
        preLoader();
        titleScreen();
    }

    private function titleScreen():void 
    {
        if (currentFrame == 2)
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, titleScreenLoop)
        }
    }

    private function titleScreenLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        titlePlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToStartScreen)
    }

    private function goToStartScreen(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (e.target == titlePlay)
        {
            trace("go to Start Screen");
            this.gotoAndStop("Start Screen");
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, titleScreenLoop)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd better re-add enter frame listeners with approppriate code each time your game shifts state. This way you'll have say four event listeners, one for death screen, one for level (main battle) screen, etc., and whenever you are about to change frames, you remove old event listener and add a new one. This will shorten the event handlers and will let you not worry about something happening in main battle while there's options menu on the screen.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you.

So each frame will have it's own enter frame. I understand now.

When I'm in the main screen, i will run the enterframe that runs the code.

When i'm on the options screen I will run that enterframe and remove the main enter frame listener.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like 'gameLoop' will be triggered every frame. You will not want to check what menu phase the game is in, IN the game loop. Add the enter frame event listener only when the player is ready for game play to start (and remember to remove it when game play stops). Structure your menu so that all happens prior to your game loop.

Comment: Ninja'd me by 8 seconds. Niiice :)